# Why does argv not work with my function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argv

So here is my code

```
from sys import argv

a,b = argv

def gcd(a,b):
    while a:
        a,b = b%a, a
    print b
```

Now if I run it from the command line with this

```
python euclidian_algorithm.py 40, 48
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "euclidian_algorithm.py", line 3, in <module>
a,b = argv
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

However if I then remove the space between the two inputs, like so

```
python euclidian_algorithm.py 40,48
```

I then get no output at all.

Now firstly I do not understand how there are too many values to unpack, when I have only put two arguments.
Secondly, why do I get no output in the second case?

Comment: `argv` contains strings, not numbers.

Comment: Also, it contains the script name as the first argument (so in the second case, `a == 'euclidian_algorithm.py'` and `b == '40,48'`). Also, you're never actually calling your function.

Comment: The comma between your arguments will also mess up things. Plus, `argv` contains the program name as its first argument, so your `argv` would look like `['euclidian_algorithm.py' '40,', 48']` in the first case.

Comment: If you litter your program with `print` statements, you'd probably have found out yourself easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) documentation,

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not).

So, `argv`'s first value will be the current script name. In the first case, you are trying to unpack three values on to two variables. That is why it fails.

In the second case, you are assigning the current script name to `a` and `48,40` to `b`.

You can confirm this by printing `argv`, `a` and `b`, like this

```
➜  Desktop  cat Test.py
from sys import argv

print argv
a, b = argv
print a, b


def gcd(a, b):
    while a:
        a, b = b % a, a
    print b
➜  Desktop  python Test.py 40, 48
['Test.py', '40,', '48']           # Note that argv has three items and first is the file name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    a, b = argv
ValueError: too many values to unpack
➜  Desktop  python Test.py 40,48 
['Test.py', '40,48']
Test.py 40,48
```

> Secondly, why do I get no output in the second case?

That is because, the function `gcd` is not invoked at all.

---

To fix this, as you are expecting only two items, I would simply assign them like this

```
a = int(argv[1])
b = int(argv[2])
```

and then invoke the function, like this

```
gcd(a, b)
```

we need to convert the values to integers as the arguments will be strings.

**Note:** Also, the arguments being passed need to be separated with white space characters, not comma. So, you would execute the program like this

```
from sys import argv

def gcd(a, b):
    while a:
        a, b = b % a, a
    print b

a = int(argv[1])
b = int(argv[2])

gcd(a, b)

➜  Desktop  python Test.py 40 48
8
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, as you can guess I am relatively new to Python!

Comment: @Ali We all were beginners once ;-) Keep learning and I would recommend reading the Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Filename euclidian_algorithm.py also one of arguments. Also, it's a very bad practice to unpack arguments like in your example.

Comment: So how should I unpack them?

Comment: *"it's a very bad practice to unpack arguments like in your example"* - says who? For a simple script like this, using e.g. `argparse` seems a little unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't separate the arguments by commas, otherwise those commas will show up in `sys.argv`. Second, the first element in `sys.argv` is the name of the script; so in your case, `sys.argv == ['euclidian_algorithm.py', '40,', '48']`.

The reason you got no output for `python euclidian_algorithm.py 40,48` was because there was no error in `a,b = argv`, since you only had two items in `argv` (the script name and the argument), *and* because you're not actually calling `gcd()`, just defining it.

If you had run it, you would have gotten an error, because `argv` contains strings, whereas you're treating `a` and `b` as `int`'s.

Here's what you should do:

```
from sys import argv

a, b = [int(x) for x in argv[1:3]]

def gcd(a, b):
    while a:
        a,b = b%a, a
    return b

print gcd(a, b)
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe, care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Why not run it and find out?

Comment: Ah, you mean `str`'s vs `int`'s. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, not a big deal, but you could have just said what the issue was in less characters than being vague :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "a,b = argv[1:]", because file name is the first value returned.